# C : if-else about variables

Tags: c, if-statement

i'm new to programming and i am a beginner in C language, i want to ask about my problem when make if else:

A code for every fruits..

A-001 for Apple with $3

A-002 for Grapes with $4

B-001 for Avocado with $2

B-002 for Orange with $1

Then the input will be 
Quantity, Fruit Code

And the output will be 
Total (Qty * price )

But when i make it like this :

`If (fruitcode=='A-001')`

It tells me the character constant too long.. what should i use for the fruit code? Is it just Integer or Characters or what?

This is my Code:

q for Qty
h for Prices
K for Fruit Code

int main(){
    int q,h,k,t;

```
printf("============================================\n");
printf("=                 Program                  =\n");
printf("============================================\n");
printf("     Fruit Code     Fruit       Prices \n");
printf("      A-001         Apple      Rp. 13.000 \n");
printf("      A-002         Grape      Rp. 16.000 \n");
printf("      B-001         Avocado    Rp. 10.000 \n");
printf("      B-002         orange     Rp. 12.000 \n");
printf("============================================\n");
printf("\n");
printf("  \n");
printf("============================================\n");
printf("=                    Form                  =\n");
printf("============================================\n");
printf("Transaction Time:  ");
scanf("%s", &t);
printf("Fruit Code : ");
scanf("%s", &k);

if(k=='A-001')
    printf("You Choose Apple");
}
else if(k='A-002'){
    printf("You Choose Grape");
}
else if(k='B-001'){
    printf("You Choose Avocado");
}
else{
    printf("You Choose orange");
}


printf("Quantity: ");
scanf("%s", &q);

getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could use any type you want, it depends on what you need to do with it. Note though that `''` is used for `char`s, not strings, and that strings can't be compared with `==`.

Comment: use "A-001" indeed of 'A-001'. "string" / 'char'

Comment: How you coded using strings or what? Show a sample of your code.

Comment: Show your code! Also, don't just dump your code here and tell you've posted it. Post an MCVE.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use double quotes for a string, not single quotes. Single quotes are only for single characters.

You also can't compare strings like that. You would need to use something like `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 2):

`fruitcode` will probably end up being a C-style *string*; i.e. it will be a pointer (of type `char*`) to a null-terminated array of `char` elements.

You'd then use something on the lines of `if (!strcmp(fruitcode, "A-001"))` to test for equality.

Note that I've used **double** quotation characters to denote a *string literal*.

(Using single quotation characters denotes something entirely different: if you enclose more than one character in single quotation characters then C interprets that as a *character array literal*. What this actually denotes is implementation defined; I think that your compiler is complaining about the length of your character array being in excess of `sizeof(int)`.)

Answer (score 0):

For comparing strings in C, use the `strcmp` function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `strcmp`:

```
if (strcmp (fruitcode, "A=001") == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, you cannot compare `fruitcode` with `"A-001"`. C's `==` operator can only compare characters, not strings of characters (only single characters).

If you want to compare them, do the following:

`strcmp(fruitcode,"A-001");`

Notice the `" "` in my answer; This implies a string. On your question, `' '` implies a character. You can't have more than one character inside `' '` (except special characters like `'\n'` that seem like 2 characters, but are represented by 1 (the line feed character in this case).